# (Proof hint)$A = \{0\}\cup\{1, 1/2, ..., 1/n, ...\}$ is Compact

Tags: compactness

Let $A = \{0\}\cup\{1, 1/2, ..., 1/n, ...\}$

I would like show that A directly satisfies the definition of compactness which is "every open cover has a finite sub-cover"

How could one generally select open cover of $A$ to start the proof?

Comment: If $U$ is an open set containing $0$. How many points are in $A-U$?

Comment: Take any open cover $\mathcal{B}=\{B_1,B_2,...,\}$ of $A$. Any one of $B_i$ covers $0$ .What can you say about this $B_i$?

Comment: @iJjjJ Doesn't it depend on U? I mean differ from case to case.

Comment: Yes but the fact is: are they finite or not?

Comment: @iJjjJ infinite

Comment: Read again my first comment and think carefully

Comment: @jJjjJ sorry. it's finite since 1/n -> 0 as n-> $\infty$